# Making a new dictionary using the key and value with the longest length from the old one, how to increment a variable at the same time?

Tags: python, dictionary

So, I have a dictionary with a bunch of keys and values, e.g.

```
dictionary = {'aety': ['yate', 'yeat', 'yeta'], 'arst': ['sart', 'sart', 'star', 'star', 'stra', 'tars', 'tsar']}
```

Each key has at least 2 values in my dictionary, hence maxlen = 2 below.

I want to make a new dictionary 'longest' that gets the key and its value that has the most amount of items in it's list, so 'arst' in this case.

I wrote this:

```
maxlen = 2

longest = {k: v for k, v in dictionary.items() if (len(v) > maxlen)}
```

The code above will do what I want it to if I manage to set maxlen = len(v) each time len(v) > maxlen (just like finding the maximum normally of a list or something) but how do I do that here?

So, at this part:

```
if (len(v) > maxlen)
```

I want this to happen:

```
len(v) = maxlen
```

How do I do that and can I fit that in that one line without writing a bunch of different lines or loops?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: @timgeb It'd just be the key and its values that has the longest length, so `longest = {'arst': ['sart', 'sart', 'star', 'star', 'stra', 'tars', 'tsar']}` in this case.

Comment: What if two keys have the same amount of elements? Do you want both in this case?

Comment: @Felix Yes, both.

Comment: Ok then @timgeb posted the answer already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the length of the longest values first

```
>>> dictionary = {'aety': ['yate', 'yeat', 'yeta'], 'arst': ['sart', 'sart', 'star', 'star', 'stra', 'tars', 'tsar']}
>>> max_len = len(max(dictionary.values(), key=len)) # 7
>>> max_len
7
```

then filter your dictionary.

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if len(v) == max_len}
{'arst': ['sart', 'sart', 'star', 'star', 'stra', 'tars', 'tsar']}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this change my current dictionary? As in, can I still print out the old dictionary with all the old values before finding the maximum length and using that?

Comment: @Mandingo your old `dictionary` is not mutated, I'm building a new dictionary with the result here.

Comment: I like `max_len2 = max(map(len, dictionary.values()))` even better ;-)

Comment: @Felix I like that too. As far as performance goes, I timed it and there does not seem to be any noticeable difference.